# Sub-Aperture Stitching interferrometry via matlab

Tags: matlab, image-stitching

I would like to stitch phase maps. For this, there is no need to move/correcte the individual subapertures laterally (ie in the x- and y-directions).
The only variables that need to be adjusted are the offset, tip and tilt.

There are already a few essays on the topic, and the mathematical path is also clear.

[mathematical background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrDbL.png)

As far as the theory ... and now to my problem. I have already implemented this, but somewhere is an error.
For testing, I create three subapertures. The Z values of two subapertures are 2, the third Z-value is 7.
As a result, R gives a correction value for the offset of '-5' and for the tilts something very close to zero, as would be expected.
If I go a step further and tilt an output subaperture, I get incorrect values for R ...

Can someone help me? I just can not find the error.
I hope that I could explain everything understandably, if not, you are free to ask.

Here you can get my *.m files.

[get the *.m files](http://gofile.me/2M6iJ/NAHXUJ673)

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've looked at the mathematical background like you've provided and at your code. I conclude that I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do and hence can't really heal you with your code. I believe the same will apply for most people here who, unless they are experts in whatever you're doing, will have not the faintest clue what is it you're asking about. What are "phase maps"? What are "subapertures"? What do you mean when you say "offset", "tip" and "tilt"? etc, etc. etc...

Comment: This probably belongs in mathematics stack exchange ? Or at least show us relevant pieces of code (not your whole file) which doesn't work as expected, and how would you expect them to work.

Comment: Apologizes the short introduction

I use a Fizeau interferometer to examine surfaces of test parts and get a kind of altitude map, the so-called phase maps. If the test part is very large, several phase maps are made from different areas and then stitchered. The measuring device is very precise in the lateral path, so that only the tilt of the test part has to be adjusted.

Comment: ...Apologizes the short introduction

I use a Fizeau interferometer to examine surfaces of test parts and get a kind of altitude map, the so-called phase maps. If the test part is very large, several phase maps are made from different areas (this are the sub-apertures) and then stitchered. The measuring device is very precise in the lateral positioning. Due to the lateral accuracy, only the tilt must be adjusted. Tip and tilt describe the tilting in different directions.